# Editing text in a ChemDraw OLE in Word

Tags: python, ms-word

StackOverflow!

I'm trying to write a Python program to replace text in a ChemDraw OLE present in a Word document.
For example I want the program to replace "num" in the below OLE with "1" ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGFNJ.png))

I've tried to write such program, but it only replaces text in the Word file, but doesn't change anything in the OLE:

```
import win32com.client
f = 'C:/Users/Adrian/Desktop/asdasdas.docx'
app = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
app.Visible = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False
app.Documents.Open(f)
app.Selection.Find.Execute("num", False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, "1", wdReplaceAll)
app.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges=True)
app.Quit()
```

Any help on how to edit OLE would be appretiated.
The word file with the OLE is available [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h-liGWFNptwXEN_I92gVA2OQXgDLlPdo/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110121244389356349941&rtpof=true&sd=true).

Comment: I had a look around for chemdraw, and it seems to be one of those packages that has a very old version (perhaps created/maintained by CambridgeSoft) and a proprietary version maintained by Perkin-Elmer (a name I must admit I last came across 40 years ago!). I also notice that there is no tag on StackOverflow for [chemdraw]. When I look at the field code for the chemdraw object in your document, I see { EMBED ChemDraw.Document.6.0 }, but I can't relate that to anything I see on the Perkin-Elmer site.

Comment: So it' difficult to know what to advise. If you have to work with very old version of ChemDraw, I doubt anyone is in a postion to help except people with that version. But going forward, perhaps better to try to deal with Perkin-Elmer or find an alternative and try to convert existing objects in Word.